# apache won't start

Tags: apache

Ok, so this has me so stumped that I don't see myself being able to solve the problem on my own. 
I am running apache on my laptop under linux, so that when I'm away from my desktop I can still work with php and mySql. Everything works great. There is nothing wrong with the syntax of the httpd.conf; apachectl configtest returns OK. However, there is one cafe that I go to where apache will not start. I'll go down the street to the next ap and apache will start without issue, but at this one cafe apache won't start. Any help will be appreciated.

The log entry that I believe to be relevant is

```
[Wed Nov 16 14:03:11 2011] [alert] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: mod_unique_id: unable to find IPv4 address of "laptop"
[Wed Nov 16 14:33:36 2011] [alert] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: mod_unique_id: unable to find IPv4 address of "laptop"
[Wed Nov 16 14:42:48 2011] [alert] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: mod_unique_id: unable to find IPv4 address of "laptop"
[Wed Nov 16 14:45:27 2011] [alert] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: mod_unique_id: unable to find IPv4 address of "laptop"
[Wed Nov 16 14:52:54 2011] [alert] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: mod_unique_id: unable to find IPv4 address of "laptop"
```

Comment: [Wed Nov 16 14:03:11 2011] [alert] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: mod_unique_id: unable to find IPv4 address of "laptop"

Answer (score 7):

If output of a command hostname is

```
# hostname
laptop
```

Giving this error in your logs:

```
(EAI 2)Name or service not known: mod_unique_id: unable to find IPv4 address of "laptop"
```

Then you should put in your /etc/hosts file sth like this :

```
127.0.0.1       laptop.homenetwork laptop localhost
::1             laptop.homenetwork laptop localhost
```

It also helps some people to put

```
ServerName localhost
```

in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file

Comment: This was exactly what I needed for putting an EC2 instance on vpc, all of the sudden stopped working. Added the result of hostname (which was basically the ip) to the first line of /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

wait will apache not start or is the port blocked in this cafe?  that would make sense to me and not that apache won't start.  also, what happens if apache is running prior to going to this cafe?  if you're still having issues, and i don't mean to sound cheeky here, but don't go to that particular cafe :)

Comment: what i mean is, port 80 might be blocked or localhost in this cafe to be more exact. they could have added security around the wifi router to block port 80, 8080, or other ports like 21 and 22.  i've never heard command line on a local machine ever being blocked.

Comment: Apache won't start. I can see how a cafe can block ports so that outside traffic can't get on their network, and I know that apache won't start if it cant find a port, but I have apache configured to listen on localhost. So do you mean that even though I'm running apache locally, apache still goes out on the network before looking at the machine its running on?

Comment: sorry, i've never experienced this, but try this [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/292932/mod-unique-id-unable-to-find-ipv4-address-of-fqdn-despite-setting-etc-hosts-and), this appears to resolved the similar issue.  if this works, please don't forget to up vote me :)

Comment: Thank Robert Van Sant. That link was right on the money. Now I know that every time I am on a public network and apache won't start, I will need to edit my host file to match what ever ip the dhcp server assigns to my laptop.

Comment: sweet, if i re-post that as the answer will you up vote it and make it as an answer :)