# Name or service not known: mod_unique_id

Tags: apache, nginx

Good Day. Can I ask what might be the cause of "Name or service not known: mod_unique_id". I've search the internet on the possible answers but it does not show the possible cause of this problem/

Comment: [*"I've searched the internet"* that's funny the first answer on google is exact what you're looking for...](https://www.google.com/search?q=Name+or+service+not+known%3A+mod_unique_id&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161011/apache-wont-start

Comment: @zedfoxus Thank you